# Save the #default_value of custom fields when editing comments

Tags: comments, forms

I added a field select list comments in a hook_form_alter. When you select and save the comment, I do not know how to preserve the value of this field when editing this comment.
My Code

```
function comment_author_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_node_zayavka_form') {
    $query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('type', 'uid', 'title', 'nid'))
      ->condition('n.type', 'brigada_type', '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
    $brigade_list = array();
    foreach ($result as $value) {
      if ($user->uid != 1) {
        if ($value->uid == $user->uid) {
          $brigade_list[$value->nid] = $value->title;
        }
      }
      else {
        $brigade_list[$value->nid] = $value->title;
      }
    }
    $form['select_brigade'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Select brigade'),
      '#options' => $brigade_list,
      '#description' => t('Please select the team that was sent to you with reference to this application.'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_field_brigade_selection', 0),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You set `variable_get('comment_field_brigade_selection')` as default value, but are you saving the value to this variable on submitting the form?

Comment: I redefined for this form of function comment_form_submit

Comment: And I think maybe I need to create a list box with field_create_field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem, has created a field using field_create_field and attached it to the essence of my comment present the type of material
My code for the solutions in the Custom Module:

```
/**
 * Реализация hook_enable().
 */
function comment_author_enable() {
    foreach (_comment_author_select_field_create() as $field) {
        field_create_field($field);
    }
    foreach (_comment_author_select_field_instances() as $instance) {
        $instance['entity_type'] = 'comment';
        $instance['bundle'] = 'comment_node_zayavka';
        field_create_instance($instance);
    }
}
function _comment_author_select_field_create(){
  $fields['brigade_select'] = array(
    'field_name' => 'brigade_select',
    'label' => t('Select an option from the list'),
    'type' => 'list_text',
    'cardinality' => '1', // change this to -1 to enable ctrl+select
    'foreign keys' => array(),
    'indexes' => array(
      'value' => array(
        0 => 'value',
      ),
    ),
    'module' => 'list',
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values_function' => '_comment_author_options_list',
    ),
  );

  return $fields;
}
function _comment_author_select_field_instances()  {
    $instances['brigade_select'] = array(
    'field_name' => 'brigade_select',
    'label' => t('Select brigade'),
    'description' => t('Please select the team that was sent to you with reference to this application.'),
    'default_value' => NULL,    // add a default value here that matches your key => index values
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'module' => 'list',
        'settings' => array(),
        'type' => 'list_default',
        'weight' => -1,
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'settings' => array(),
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => -1,
      ),
    ),
    'required' => 1,
    'settings' => array(
      'user_register_form' => FALSE,
    ),
    'widget' => array(
      'active' => 1,
      'module' => 'options',
      'settings' => array(),
      'type' => 'options_select',
      'weight' => '-1',
    ),
  );
  return $instances;
}
function _comment_author_options_list(){
global $user;
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('type', 'uid', 'title', 'nid'))
    ->condition('n.type', 'brigada_type', '=');
 $result = $query->execute();
 $brigade_list = array();
    foreach($result as $value){
        if($user->uid != 1){
            if($value->uid == $user->uid){
             $brigade_list[$value->nid] = $value->title;
            }   
        }else{
        $brigade_list[$value->nid] = $value->title;
        }
    }
    return $brigade_list;
}
```